# Solve the initial value problem with 4 conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Slove
>   $$
>  \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
> u_{tt}=u_{xx}+\sin 2x &\mbox{ $0\lt x\lt\pi,t\gt0$} \\
>   u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0 \\
> u(x,0)=u_t(x,0)=0
>        \end{array} \right.
> $$

How to solve these kind equations? I already know the solution like 
$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}\\
u(x,0)=\phi(x),u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)
\end{array} \right.
$$

Is there a general solution for the equation above?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make the substitution $v=u-\frac 14 \sin 2x$ to reduce the equation to the form $v_{tt}=v_{xx}$. Do you know what to do from here?

Comment: the substitution is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem in particular, [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle) works *very* nicely. Incidentally, there happens to be an online source with a [walkthrough](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~lallen/LectureDec5.pdf) of almost exactly the same problem. See if you can follow through it to get the general procedure for these kinds of problems.